# angularjs Unable to update the directive on drop down list change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Unable to update the directive on drop down list change using anuglar js .
Here is my app code

**html code**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="opt" ng-options="font.title for font in fonts" ng-change="change(opt)">
    </select>
    <p>
        {{opt}}</p>
    <br />
    <h3>
        Text Is
    </h3>
    <div id="tstDiv" testdir ct="ct">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller and directive code**

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.fonts = [
    { title: "Arial", text: 'Url for Arial' },
    { title: "Helvetica", text: 'Url for Helvetica' }
];
        $scope.opt = $scope.fonts[0];
        $scope.change = function (option) {
            $scope.opt = option;
        }
    })
        .directive("testDir", function ($timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    ct: '=ct'
                },
                link: function ($scope, $elm, $attr) {
                    document.getElementById('tstDiv').innerHTML = $scope.selectedTitle;
                }
            };
        });
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cbqju/

Comment: You should be using the directive like test-dir and not testdir

Comment: i have created a plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/KgcCt43qmEBhvGZaIDsp?p=preview

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal few doubts, 1) why did u modify the div .. <div id="tstDiv" test-dir ct="ct">
        </div> And what if there are more than 1 drop down and i want to update their value too in the div like ddl1.title + ddl2.title in to div

Comment: i dont see ct being defined in code anywhere you must pass the selected model to directive which is opt

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal i meant opt="opt" in the div

Comment: this is because you have to pass the selected model to directive because opt is the selected model so you can watch on the opt values and make changes in div based on selection change pls see documentation for more details http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive if you want more details we can continue this on the chat

Comment: thnks @Ajaybeniwal....

Comment: I dont see why you would want to access the element through the dom with `document.findElementById`.  That seems like totally the wrong way to manage the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @Ajaybeniwal comments here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KgcCt43qmEBhvGZaIDsp?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll want to $watch for a change in that variable
Your link function should look something like

```
scope: {
    ct: '=ct',
    opt: '=opt'
},
link: function ($scope, $elm, $attr) {
    $scope.$watch('opt', function(newOpt, oldOpt) {
        document.getElementById('tstDiv').innerHTML = newOpt.title;
    });
}
```

Comment: tried but not working....would be helpful if u could provide a working fiddle.me new to angular js